# Alpine Expression Error: createFormComponent is not defined

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, alpine.js

I am using Alpine JS in .NET Core 6 MVC project. I have loaded the alpine js file from https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js. I then added the following code in the Home/Index.cshtml file.

```
<form id="myForm"
  x-data="createFormComponent()" 
  x-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">

  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" 
    x-model="email" />

  <span class="error" style="display: none"
    x-show="error"
    x-text="error"
  ></span>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts {

   <script>
  (function () {
    'use strict';

    window.createFormComponent = function () {
      return {
        email: '',
        error: '',

        onSubmit($event) {
          this.error = !this.email 
            ? 'You must enter an email address' 
            : '';
        },
      };
    };
  })();
</script>

}
```

But when I access the page in the browser, it always throws the error "Alpine Expression Error: createFormComponent is not defined". I have tried to put it into a js file and load it. Also tried to define the component in alpine:init event. None of them worked. The same code works in plain html file served from IIS. I am not sure what is wrong here. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure add js in your `_Layout.cshtml` or in your current page `@section Scripts {...}`  like below:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
```

Note: HTML  `defer` attribute must be added.

Comment: It is working fine in the sample app. Checking in the main app. I did add the defer but I added it before the src tag and moving to the end seems to have made the difference.